# RUN apt-get update is not running

Tags: apt, docker, php, docker-compose

```
FROM php:7.3.33-apache-bullseye

RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) mysqli opcache
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install sockets
# Instalar ifconfig
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install ... && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html/validator-web

RUN mkdir -p /var/log/validator-web

COPY ./validator-logs /var/log/validator-web

COPY .. /var/www/html/validator-web


# Configuración de red
#RUN ip addr add 192.168.100.99/24 dev eth0
RUN docker network create mi-red

ERROR:
docker compose up
[+] Building 20.0s (9/15)
 => [php internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                         0.4s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 4.41kB                                                                                                                                                                           0.4s 
 => [php internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                            0.5s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                  0.4s 
 => [php internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/php:7.3.33-apache-bullseye                                                                                                                                0.8s 
 => [php  1/11] FROM docker.io/library/php:7.3.33-apache-bullseye@sha256:b9872cd287ef72bc17d45d713aa2742f3d3bcf2503fea2506fd93aa94995219f                                                                        0.0s 
 => CANCELED [php internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                  17.7s 
 => => transferring context: 2.36MB                                                                                                                                                                             17.6s 
 => CACHED [php  2/11] RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) mysqli opcache                                                                                                                                      0.0s 
 => CACHED [php  3/11] RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql                                                                                                                                                      0.0s 
 => CACHED [php  4/11] RUN docker-php-ext-install sockets                                                                                                                                                        0.0s 
 => ERROR [php  5/11] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install ... && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*                                                                                                                  17.7s 
------
 > [php  5/11] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install ... && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*:
5.723 Err:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security/main amd64 Packages
5.723   Hash Sum mismatch
5.723   Hashes of expected file:
5.723    - Filesize:251960 [weak]
5.723    - SHA256:cacc0d76f693545cb89efd8cea5c7d458fcca04179e10fb50f0c0c9f1b825575
5.723   Hashes of received file:
5.723    - SHA256:4ea9d1187600c25a513d4c40dc0686149f64c1d3be9e6e456418440edd87b8c8
5.723    - Filesize:251960 [weak]
5.723   Last modification reported: Sun, 16 Jul 2023 21:28:38 +0000
5.723   Release file created at: Sun, 16 Jul 2023 22:00:38 +0000
13.79 Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages [8183 kB]
13.79 Ign:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages
14.02 Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates/main amd64 Packages [14.8 kB]
14.27 Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages [8183 kB]
16.33 Err:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages
16.33   Hash Sum mismatch
16.33   Hashes of expected file:
16.33    - Filesize:8182636 [weak]
16.33    - SHA256:c19e2c4d682c3057a41bbc275870d7d28b8ec52abf2859eee2452119a075dee5
16.33    - MD5Sum:7de22ee2aeab95f0fd770003550c4a80 [weak]
16.33   Hashes of received file:
16.33    - SHA256:a57e1b6f26e816dfb393c703d1fbcd7baf1861dcef6ab45a02d008139d3abb20
16.33    - MD5Sum:64ced165ff87304d55bf6f5489d6f70b [weak]
16.33    - Filesize:8182636 [weak]
16.33   Last modification reported: Sat, 29 Apr 2023 08:57:15 +0000
16.33   Release file created at: Sat, 10 Jun 2023 08:52:21 +0000
16.35 Fetched 8653 kB in 13s (670 kB/s)
16.35 Reading package lists...
16.42 E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/bullseye-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages.xz  Hash Sum mismatch
16.42    Hashes of expected file:
16.42     - Filesize:251960 [weak]
16.42     - SHA256:cacc0d76f693545cb89efd8cea5c7d458fcca04179e10fb50f0c0c9f1b825575
16.42    Hashes of received file:
16.42     - SHA256:4ea9d1187600c25a513d4c40dc0686149f64c1d3be9e6e456418440edd87b8c8
16.42     - Filesize:251960 [weak]
16.42    Last modification reported: Sun, 16 Jul 2023 21:28:38 +0000
16.42    Release file created at: Sun, 16 Jul 2023 22:00:38 +0000
16.42 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye/main/binary-amd64/Packages.xz  Hash Sum mismatch
16.42    Hashes of expected file:
16.42     - Filesize:8182636 [weak]
16.42     - SHA256:c19e2c4d682c3057a41bbc275870d7d28b8ec52abf2859eee2452119a075dee5
16.42     - MD5Sum:7de22ee2aeab95f0fd770003550c4a80 [weak]
16.42    Hashes of received file:
16.42     - SHA256:a57e1b6f26e816dfb393c703d1fbcd7baf1861dcef6ab45a02d008139d3abb20
16.42     - MD5Sum:64ced165ff87304d55bf6f5489d6f70b [weak]
16.42     - Filesize:8182636 [weak]
16.42    Last modification reported: Sat, 29 Apr 2023 08:57:15 +0000
16.42    Release file created at: Sat, 10 Jun 2023 08:52:21 +0000
16.42 E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install ... && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
```

Comment: please format your logs, they are currently unreadable.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.